# Implementing PaymentResultWithDataListener in RazorPay Android SDK

Tags: android, payment-gateway

Excuse the trivial question. I am doing RazorPay integration for the first time.

In my app I want to carry forward a couple of strings about the user's order. This is NOT the order as defined by RazorPay.

I see that the interface `PaymentResultWithDataListener` provides `PaymentData` in the callback. How to I send extra data to `Checkout` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PaymentData` contains following fields

1. Contact number of the user
2. Email address of the user
3. Razorpay payment id
4. Razorpay order id(It will be present in case you are using Razorpay orders API and sending order id to Checkout)
5. Signature, which can be used to capture payment on backend(not compulsory to make use of it)
6. Data, A JSON object which will contain data like payment id, signature etc.

If you want to send any custom data from your side. You can send it in from of JSON object in checkout option with key as `notes`

Example:

```
//notesData is json object which contain your custom data
options.put("notes", notesData);
```

This notes will be available in DashBoard and you will get it in payment details also when you fetch payment detail via API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried using notes. Unfortunately, it is not carried back to the listener. Regarding the Order API, I am not able to find any kind of documentation or sample code for Android SDK

Comment: notes are not carried forward to listener but it will be available in Dashboard and also when you fetch payment detail via API it will be available. You can find oders API doc here(https://docs.razorpay.com/page/orders). Once you create order id using API, you can send it to checkout in options, key will be "order_id"